# Querying in Entity Framework for fill combobox of foreign key

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a `ComboBox` of provinces :

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    using (AbEntities c = new AbEntities())
    {
        comboBox1.DataSource = c.tbl_Province.ToList();
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "ID";
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Province";
    }
}
```

Now I want to list cities for each province in another combobox.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString() != null)
    {
        int pvc = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString());
        string sqlString = "SELECT ID,City FROM tbl_City Where ProvinceID = pvc"

        using (AbEntities c = new AbEntities())
        {
            comboBox2.DataSource = c.tbl_City.ToList();
            comboBox2.ValueMember = "ID";
            comboBox2.DisplayMember = "City";
        }
    }
}
```

I wrote the following query. But cities are not filtered

Comment: What's with the SQL string? XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any filtering in your code. May be you should apply some like this:

```
comboBox2.DataSource = c.tbl_City.Where(x=>x.ProvinceID == pvc).ToList();
```

Explanation:

The loose SQL-query string in your code has no application. Since your post is tagged with `entity-framework` I assume that `AbEntities` is a `DataContext`.
In this case `tbl_City` implements the `IQueryable` interface and allows you to call `Where` directly in your code. In this example I used the method syntax. 
The `ToList()` call will execute the query and materialize the results.
This can also be accomplished using the query syntax:

```
comboBox2.DataSource = (from   x in c.tbl_City
                        where  x.ProvinceID == pvc
                        select x).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to query your DbSet, e.g.:

```
c.tbl_City.Where(c => c.ProvinceID == pvc).ToList();
```

Further:

there is no relation between the SQL statement and the filter.

You might want to read something about [linq](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b),

And here is more about EF: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/querying-entity-graph-in-entity-framework.aspx